# Image.FromStream() issue C# at the time of image manipulation

Tags: c#, imaging

I'm working with JPG image type and this line `image = Image.FromStream(ms);` is giving an error `Parameter is not valid`.
What is wrong with this code?

```
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          Image partial=null;
          Rectangle bounds;
          Guid id;

          if (diff != null)
          {
            ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            var data = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(diff, typeof(byte[]));

            UnpackScreenCaptureData(data, out partial, out bounds,out id);
            Image imgfirst = (Image)firstImg;
            UpdateScreen(ref imgfirst, partial, bounds);
          }
        }

        public static void UnpackScreenCaptureData(byte[] data, out Image image, out Rectangle bounds, out Guid id)
        {
          // Unpack the data that is transferred over the wire.
          // Create byte arrays to hold the unpacked parts.
          const int numBytesInInt = sizeof(int);
          int idLength = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray().Length;
          int imgLength = data.Length - 4 * numBytesInInt - idLength;
          byte[] topPosData = new byte[numBytesInInt];
          byte[] botPosData = new byte[numBytesInInt];
          byte[] leftPosData = new byte[numBytesInInt];
          byte[] rightPosData = new byte[numBytesInInt];
          byte[] imgData = new byte[imgLength];
          byte[] idData = new byte[idLength];

          // Fill the byte arrays.
          Array.Copy(data, 0, topPosData, 0, numBytesInInt);
          Array.Copy(data, numBytesInInt, botPosData, 0, numBytesInInt);
          Array.Copy(data, 2 * numBytesInInt, leftPosData, 0, numBytesInInt);
          Array.Copy(data, 3 * numBytesInInt, rightPosData, 0, numBytesInInt);
          Array.Copy(data, 4 * numBytesInInt, imgData, 0, imgLength);
          Array.Copy(data, 4 * numBytesInInt + imgLength, idData, 0, idLength);

          // Create the bitmap from the byte array.          
          MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgData, 0, imgData.Length);
          ms.Write(imgData, 0, imgData.Length);
          image = Image.FromStream(ms);
          ....
        }
```

Comment: What is the exception being thrown?

Comment: when this line " image = Image.FromStream(ms);" execute then i am getting error and error message is "Parameter is not valid".

Comment: i think there is very minor mistake which i am not being able to understand.

Comment: What exactly is diff? Where does it come from?

Comment: i was trying to compare two jpg images. first jpg image store in firstImg variable and second image store in secondImg variable and difference between two images store in diff variable.

Comment: Right after the last `Array.Copy` add this line `uint header = BitConverter.ToUInt32(imgData, 0);` and tell us the value of the `header` variable.

Comment: the value i got 4060282880 now tell me what would be the fix

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to reset your `MemoryStream` to position 0.
You can accomplish this by calling the `Seek()` method on the memory stream:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgData, 0, imgData.Length);
ms.Write(imgData, 0, imgData.Length);

ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);  // Set stream position to 0.    

image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Comment: Also, this does not make any sense:  `MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgData, 0, imgData.Length);  ms.Write(imgData, 0, imgData.Length);` Create stream from array and after that write that array to stream again?

Comment: @Thomas: Did you compare the values for imgLength, topPosData,... with the original ones? I think we do need more code in order to help you.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. The imgData is written twice to the same stream.